# What makes a question historically significant?

Tags: discussion, historical-lock

There are some questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke) one which are off topic and do not follow the rules but still are not deleted. They are kept due to "historical significance." Does that mean that it has enough upvotes and answers to be kept? And if so, what is the number required to be historically significant. Surely just because a question is popular and gains many answers doesn't mean that it should be kept even though it is off topic. So why do such questions exist if they are clearly against the rules of the website?

Comment: Look at the number of votes, views, and favorites. And a user (NullUserException) locked the post, not a bot.

Comment: It's a judgement call.  As you can see, the post that you referenced is wildly off-topic, but it's very old, has many views and a number of [outside links](https://www.google.com/search?q=linkto%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F234075) to it.

Comment: Popularity is only part of it.  It's usually due to inbound links.  If a question has been linked and referenced on numerous external sites, it would be better if users coming in via those links actually saw the question and not a deleted question notice.

Comment: The votes don't matter *as* much. While votes are a cool indicator of how "useful" it has been to visitors over the years, the **views** are a much better indicator, grouped with how valuable and *detailed* the content is.

Comment: @gunr2171 not an average user though, NullUserException used to be a mod and he would have locked it then.  Regular users can't lock questions like that.

Comment: @psubsee2003, true. Mods are users too. What I meant was that the system itself did not lock the post, a human did it.

Comment: Isn't "historical significance" a misnaming then?  I have an example from 2013, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/python-simplest-way-to-get-list-of-values-from-dict, which led me to search this.  Most historical questions I have seen come from 2008, 2009 when the direction and purpose of the site was still being formed.  My case above is one which should be deleted due to its search/find tutorial notion, yet other metrics lead it to be historical.  We knew better when that question was written.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is based on community consensus.  There is no general case rule; they are discussed on a case by case basis to determine if the community feels that the post is adding sufficient value to warrant keeping it around or not.