# Make historical question a votable category

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I rarely open the 10k tools, simply because I see there too many interesting, though non-conforming questions voted into deletion.

The time people spent to answer a question [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/325862/772868) is completely ignored and disrespected.
Since the [current procedere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266419/772868) is to discuss such post case-by-case, chances are that a large number of them are deleted.

My proposal is thus to add a historical-question category to vote for, for questions that meet certain minimal standards.

Comment: Something similar is being discussed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261807/we-should-have-a-question-status-similar-to-locking-that-non-mods-can-set-on-pos

Comment: I love how people down vote and then don't show the minimum amount of decency by at least explaining why. I don't understand why this isn't a valid question. Gotta love the haters.

Comment: @Anthony: -1 on MSO means: the voter disagrees. No more than that. The votes have no influence on my rep. The answer gives some good reason. Not that I agree completely ...

Answer (score 4):

While I'm not happy with SO's deletionism and the... less than satisfying solutions that are provided for off-topic questions, the debate's been had. It was a long and very painful one.

This suggestion doesn't look like it would provide anything except start the battle again. You will always be able to find loads of people willing to historical-lock *anything*, so if you introduce this you'd have to introduce historical-un-locking by vote, too, which you'll *also* find loads of people for.

The right solution would be for someone to [build an archive for questions that get deleted on SO.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122249/building-an-archive-of-deleted-questions) So far, though, no one has been willing to invest the energy to do this (myself included).

Comment: See also: [Unofficial Stack Overflow deleted question archive now available](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124850/unofficial-stack-overflow-deleted-question-archive-now-available)