# Question and answer removed, was a useful bookmark

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions

There was a Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file) that was so useful for us that we had it as a Slackbot response. It was recently taken down. [Here it is on the Way Back Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180131114857/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file): it has an accepted answer with 3194 upvotes, which makes its removal puzzling.

For what it's worth, it's our company's opinion that it shouldn't have been yanked.

It was probably useful to other folks who need a particular version of Xcode and don't want to rely on the App Store versions. I'm sure a lot goes into the decision to delete a posting, but I'd like to suggest it be returned.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like the deletion was in error, as was the closure. The question was not specifically off-topic. The fact that the answers pointed to an off-site resource as helpful is not relevant, as most answers link to outside sources.

Comment: sometimes I don't get it, why there is so much garbage floating around and never gets deleted. But on the other hand a valuable highly visited (1m) visits question/answer pair is vaporized, because someone thinks it doesn't fit the rules of SO. Thanks to mod @Jon to bring it back to all of us.

Comment: The question could not have been deleted by users if it had been a duplicate target. Yet, obviously, not a single question had been duplicated to this "useful bookmark", despite the fact there are [hundreds](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=download+dmg+is%3Aq) or perhaps [thousands](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=download+xcode+is%3Aq) of candidates. The effort of closing a single duplicate would have served the SO community _and_ protected the question.

Comment: @theMayer Not sure how you think the question was closed or delete in error... it took 5 people to close it and 10 to delete it; literally the maximum possible required to do so for a question. No, the question was intentionally closed and deleted. Whether that was the *best thing per the community's decision*, however, is another matter.

Comment: @TylerH by error, I don't mean accidentally, I mean without appropriate thought and/or rationale.

Comment: @theMayer That's a pretty big assumption, and one that's ultimately just an opinion.

Comment: @TylerH - maybe so, but the community moderators agree. Why belabor the point?

Comment: @theMayer Well, one moderator agrees, but anyway, I'm belaboring your point because your point is wrong.

Comment: @TylerH, while I welcome technical disagreements, you should not present your opinion as fact, particularly when the outcome was the opposite. My point was that there were no grounds for closing. I don't care that 10 people agreed, I looked at it, and it was an overzealous and, in this case, harmful action to delete the question.

Comment: @theMayer Nor should you, that's *my* point. Closure is a community thing. Members of the community voted to close it, and twice as many members of the community voted to delete it. This is their prerogative. And if you bother to read into the intent of Jon's answer, you'll see it wasn't restored because it was on-topic, but because it has a lot of views and regular updates. That's about as 'grandfathered in' as it gets here at SO. So I'm simply pointing out that your statement "it looks like the deletion was in error, as was the closure" is wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the question having a million views and the main upvoted answer being regularly updated by the community - it does seem a shame to lose it.

The question has been restored and a wiki-lock applied to it so that no new answers can be added. The main answer has been converted into a community wiki and all other answers have been removed to reduce noise.

Hopefully the community will continue to provide updates and those that reference it can continue to benefit from it.

Comment: This question & answer are performing a similar service that the [C++ tag wiki does](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info). Cool thing about that tag wiki is that it does not attract additional low-quality answers the way a question asking "How to download..." does.

Comment: FWIW: I voted to delete the question, as the question doesn't look particularly good in today's terms, and all the answers are link (or image) only. I didn't see, and still don't see, the worth of this question as a signpost, as people can go to Apple's Dev page themselves. Locking the question prevents new answers, thankfully, but moving it altogether to the tag-wiki as @Mogsdad suggest is even better in my opinion, so as that the question does not serve as an example of a "great question" due to its vote count.

Comment: @Adriaan moving it to the tag wiki precludes a large amount of users being able to update it without peer review. Since <20k users have been maintaining it without issue - that doesn't seem a worthwhile trade off. (Not to mention that tag wikis don't get returned in search results etc...). I agree it's not great - but it's of use - so we might as well keep it as is.

Comment: how is it of use exactly? It is little more than a list of links to the official download page, which we can find just as easily on google. FWIW I triggered the train of delete votes, and I based my reasoning on the answer Cody gave me [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317571/1843331). Note that I don't mind being told I took wrong actions, but there seems to be some disagreement about how to handle such posts

Comment: @TimCastelijns it's a tricky one... Is it causing harm by being visible - no. Is it of use - yes & no. It has a million views and climbing, it got noticed fairly quickly it was missing, it's being updated periodically by the community... people *are* apparently finding it *useful*... We can debate how useful a post of links you can find elsewhere actually is and a new post trying to do the same wouldn't be particularly welcome, but it's there now, people are using it, so while I might not find it useful, others do, therefore there's more harm in its removal than just letting it be.

Comment: @JonClements I understand your reasoning. I don't fully agree with it, but as you said it's tricky. Thanks.

Comment: _"Is it causing harm by being visible - no"_ -- I think "no" is the wrong answer. I can believe "not enough to warrant deletion". But every Q&A that doesn't fit the Stack Overflow model does _some_ harm. It clogs search results and makes less thoughtful people think that similar Q&A can be added to Stack Overflow, based on the example. I'm not saying that means the question at hand should've been deleted, but I am saying one should be careful to not overstate the harmlessness of the content.

Comment: @JonClements Now that the question has settled down, I've flagged about half the comments under the accepted answer as they are all 'thanks' comments or variations on that theme.