# Why was this question locked?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete, historical-lock

A while ago I asked a rather unpopular question (which was subsequently auto deleted by the community) about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19926867/1767412) with 75 downvotes and which more or less only consists of an opinion and a wrong statement. Someone then made the following comment, suggesting we delete the whole mess:

> As always, problem questions begets problem answers. The question is bad, it has been dealt with. Now we just need to finish the job

After garnering nine deletion votes, it was then "locked" because it "*has historical significance*". I fail to see what's historically significant about either the question, which is a dupe, or any of the answers. The community got within a hair of deleting it permanently, so clearly I'm not alone in this opinion.

The question is closed as a duplicate and none of the answers seem to offer anything that isn't already outlined on the [duplicate here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-can-i-stop-the-browser-back-button-using-javascript) with at least as much clarity.

Who locked it and why?

Comment: _“Who locked it”_ — You can clearly see this in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19926641/timeline#history_1f5c8acf-94c2-4a16-9fa0-8ac35252f6fb), but why is this relevant?

Comment: @user4642212 - I didn't know whether a single person can do this or if it required a community vote, which is why I asked about *who* - and thanks for the timeline link. That said, the "why" part is more what I'm after. If we have a voting system that allows for deletion, I'd like to understand why this individual made the choice to cancel out the votes of 9 other community members.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What makes a question historically significant?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266418/what-makes-a-question-historically-significant)

Comment: That is literally *the* correct answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### The question is clearly and obviously helpful (a good signpost) and should not be deleted.

I locked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19926641/3773011)<sup>1</sup> when handling a flag intended to bring the question's potential deletion to the attention of the moderators. I locked the question in order to prevent people from deleting a question which was *clearly and obviously* useful. With 207,199 views, the question is *clearly* serving well in a duplicate question's primary role of being a signpost to the dup-target question. That's 2,496 people per month that view the question and get a link to the duplicate, which is an average of 82 people *every single day*.

In fact, the question and its highest upvoted answer are arguably more helpful than the question it's closed as a duplicate of. This question's highest scored answer has a score of 265, which is 0.001279 votes/view. If this question had the same number of views as the duplicate-target, then the score would be 701, which is 4.25 *times* as many votes as the highest scoring answer on the duplicate target.

#### Why did you want to delete a question which is *clearly* helpful to people?

From [your earlier question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401844), it appeared your primary issue was with the negatively scored accepted answer, rather than the question. Deleting a question which is useful to thousands of people every month just to get rid of an answer you don't like is inappropriate. [Deleting answers is a privilege given at 20k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). Users with >20k reputation could delete-vote the negatively scored answer, if they choose.

Deleting useful questions shouldn't be a surrogate action for deleting answers which you don't like. Frankly, I view doing so as an abuse of the [10k delete-vote on questions privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). However, please note that I don't mean you shouldn't vote to delete poor questions, just that you shouldn't be using deleting a helpful question as a way to delete an answer, particularly when that question is *obviously* helpful to a large number of people.

To reiterate what the [10k delete-vote on questions privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) says:

> #### When should I delete questions?
>
> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be deleted.
>
> Before voting to delete, please check whether there are **any good answers**; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!
>
> Also, be cautious when deleting questions closed as **duplicates**; [they can serve as a signpost](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/), directing users to useful answers on another question.

#### In this case, merging is a potential alternative to locking

In my opinion, it would be reasonable, and probably better, to merge [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19926641/3773011) into its [duplicate-target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-can-i-stop-the-browser-back-button-using-javascript). I did not do so at the time because merging is irreversible. Given the number of people who had voted to delete and the fact that there was previously a Meta question about the accepted answer, I considered it likely there would be a Meta question asking about how the question was handled. I didn't want to have performed an irreversible merge prior to everyone getting a chance to say their peace.

#### The comment you quoted

While I agree that problem questions tend to beget problem answers, the existence of a problem answer doesn't inherently mean the question is a problem. This question is not a problem question. Other than the fact that the question is a duplicate, there's nothing inherently wrong with that question. The logic used in that comment is flawed.

We don't delete duplicate questions which are good signposts. They still serve a useful function.

---

1. I also cleared the delete-votes, because A) it looks poor to have a question sitting at 9 delete-votes indefinitely, and B) leaving a locked question with delete-votes makes the [10k tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) less useful.

Comment: I would say merge - it is not usable sign post, as it is basically the same question as duplicate one. OP clearly just dumped their requirement without any research and why some people land on this one instead of duplicate - only Google knows. Duplicate has basically the same title, and maybe it only needs to be tweaked a bit to remove unnecessary reference to PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply and explanation. I don't agree that the view count makes a question "*clearly and obviously useful*". The view count only reflects the high google ranking.  The question itself is poorly researched and shows little no to no effort by the asker. If it was asked today it would undoubtedly be closed and probably deleted. The top voted answer is more or less a dupe of JonBrave's answer on the dupe with much less detail and explanation.

Comment: ***Why did you want to delete a question which is clearly helpful to people?*** I think both the question is bad. The accepted answer is bad. All the other answers are dupes of answers on the dupe. A signpost is most useful when it brings someone to a question they wouldn't otherwise have found. In this case, the dupe has a *very similar title* and ranks right there with this one in nearly any search you perform. If the question was deleted users would almost certainly go directly to the place the signpost was pointing. I understand the concept of a good signpost but I don't think this is one.

Comment: I'm not strictly against merging but again, I don't see that anything here offers a distinct value that's not already present on the dupe. Those 9 delete votes were cast by other high ranking users here and frankly I view clearing those votes and locking the question as an abuse of your moderator privilege. I don't mean you shouldn't lock Q&A that has lasting value, but in this case it feels a lot like community sentiment is being undermined.

Comment: @billynoah It's got a historical lock. basically even if the content isn;'t useful, if it was asked in a time where SO was different (i.e several years ago) then we historically lock it to represent that now it's unnaceptable, but then it was okay to do.

Comment: @billynoah I am not in position to fully judge answers (except the one with downvotes), maybe question could just be deleted because answers don't bring anything significant. However, merging is most likely better compromise in this case because it will not upset the answerers. And when merged, people will be in better position to judge all the answers and clean up if needed.

Comment: @billynoah The 9 delete votes you mention is representation of the 9 users that wanted it gone. Noway are user that didn't want it gone able to cast any votes to counter the delete votes. They have to wait until it's deleted to do so. Applying the logic that the community wanted it deleted isn't reasonable unless you know how many users would have un-deleted it The score on your previous post and on this post may be more accurately describing the community's opinion on the matter.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar - agreed.

Comment: @Scratte - that had crossed my mind as well. Probably not the time or place to open a can of worms but the dynamic you described seems like a bit of a shortcoming in the deletion criteria. If someone were to open "deletion proceedings" and then things had to reach certain net before being deleted that might possibly cast this in a different light.